# Tension in thread

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

We know a thread or string experiences the same tension force throughout the whole length,but when we tie a knot in the thread,why does the tension force become different in the two sides of the knot? Is it possible to explain it through newtonian mechanics?

Comment: Can you show an example?  Why do you think the tension would be different?

Answer (score 0):

Unless that knot is tying the string to some stationary object (in which case it's more properly called a "hitch" rather than a "knot"), the tension force is necessarily the same on both sides. Otherwise, there'd be a net force one way or the other, and the knot would accelerate in that direction. (Moreover, if just tying a knot in a string resulted in any such net force, you could trivially construct a perpetual motion machine, thereby solving the energy crisis, remediating climate change, etc, etc.)